# Azure AD Cannot hit login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create authentication for my App via Azure Active Directory but have had little luck.

I created a new Azure Active Directory instance in portal.azure.com and copied the "Directory ID" (Click on Azure Active Directory and then properties) and still cannot authenticate.

I am trying to use https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}. Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong or need to try in the portal?

Answer:
The above won't work directly by itself.

You must set up OWIN and enable an OWIN startup class.

This is what the startup class should look like:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
             ClientId = "{Registered app object id}", //This value is found in the app configuration page and is app specific
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}" //This value will NEVER change as it is the tenant ID
            });
```

Comment: For authorization, the endpoint is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/authorize`. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code.

Comment: @GauravMantri I am using OWIN though not oauth2. That being said I should at least be able to hit the url above. Though I did try with the URL above and I got "This page can't be found".

Comment: Even when I tried to hit this URL (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}`), I got the same response as yours.

Comment: @GauravMantri I fixed it, using openId, apparently I skipped a step and didn't replace the proper object ID to allow it to function.

Comment: The `ClientId` is not the same as the "Directory ID". The `ClientId` is the id of the appplication registered in the active directory.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the issue has been fixed, but I would like to add more information for others that have same issue: My recommendation is to follow the steps of [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp-v1) that explains what you need to do and what to add to these fields, such as TenantId or ClientId.